# Problem with colorama library and input function in python

Tags: python, io, colorama

Consider following code:

```
import colorama
colorama.init(autoreset=True)

answer = input(colorama.Back.BLACK + colorama.Fore.YELLOW + 'What is 5 takeaway 5?').strip()

if answer == '0' or answer == 'zero':
   print(colorama.Back.GREEN + "You're right!")
else:
   print(colorama.Back.RED + "It's actually zero")

print(colorama.Back.GREEN + 'Thank you!')
```

I want the input to be colored and it is, but when the print ends - all the following text is black

[image: example of code. Source: https://ibb.co/3T6cBhm]

putting a `colorama.Back.RESET` at the end of either print produces the same result.

Is there **any** way to fix this, while having the colored input?

Comment: what do you mean? you want to colour the whole line green?

Comment: I don't want the part of the line to be black. As you can see, the last line comprises two background colors simultaneously: it's green, then after the print text ends, the newline is black and I don't want that

Comment: this might be a problem with your terminal, command prompt doesn't give the same output as you have now, what are you using?

Comment: @WhatsThePoint I am using VSCode powershell. Are you sure you're using the current version of code with the `print(colorama.Back.GREEN + 'Thank you!')` line?

Comment: Also take into account that cmd's default background color is black, hence you can't tell if the print line stays black or not. In that case I'd suggest you check this with, for example, `colorama.Back.BLUE` in the input